# Only two of four radial-gradients showing

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I have used the following code to my css file to get a gradient at all corners, however, I am only getting gradient at the top two corners.

Can anyone please let me know the correct way to do this?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0hxmb9j/1/

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fbe0be;
}

body:before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at top left,
       rgba(212,235,235,1), rgba(155,179,208,.3) 70.71%),
  radial-gradient(circle at top right,
        rgba(83,98,127,1), rgba(155,179,208,.3) 70.71%),
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,
       rgba(122,97,70,1), rgba(251,224,190,.7) 70.71%),
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,
       rgba(122,97,70,1), rgba(251,224,190,.7) 70.71%)
}
```

Comment: considering the fact that all of them are on the top of each other, the last one will be hardly seen due to the 3 on the top of it even if you are using semi-transparent color

Comment: OK. So, increase the transparency from the top down.

Comment: no, you need to decrease the one of the top. Here is an illustration of your gradient with solid color: https://jsfiddle.net/g0jw43st/ .. the very bottom one has only a small section to it